# bootstrap carousel control not changing to previous slide

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Oddly enough the carousel will slide to the next slide, but it won't work for previous. 
I'm not too familiar with jsfiddle just yet, but as you can see, the next will get hilighted, but the previous will not.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHJNC/)

```
<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide col-lg-offset-1" data-ride="carousel" style="max-width: 970px;">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner rs-slider">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://www.nerisbakery.com/images/img-hero-family.jpg" alt="..." class="full-width" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="left: 0; bottom: 0;">
                    <p class="family"> <i>LtoR:</i> Paul A. Neri, Sr. - <i>Founder</i>

                        <br />Paul A. Neri, Jr - <i>Vice President</i>

                        <br />Theresa M. Neri, Jr - <i>Co-Founder</i>

                        <br />Dominick A. Neri, Jr - <i>President</i>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.nerisbakery.com/images/img-hero-family.jpg" alt="..." class="full-width" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="left: 0; bottom: 35px;">
                    <p class="largest">We are one of the largest bakeries in the United States</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.nerisbakery.com/images/img-hero-family.jpg" alt="..." class="full-width" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="left: 0; bottom: 0;">
                    <p class="wholesale">Our state of the art, 260,000 sq.ft. facility is equipped to handle any job large or small. As the bakers for some of the country's most famous brand names, if you have enjoyed a bagel anywhere in the northeast, it was probably baked here at Neri's.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.nerisbakery.com/images/img-hero-family.jpg" alt="..." class="full-width" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="left: 0; bottom: 0;">
                    <p class="innovation">Neri's always has remained on the cutting edge of industry innovation. We have been prominently featured in many publications throughout the years and sited as an example of baking excellence!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://www.nerisbakery.com/images/img-hero-family.jpg" alt="..." class="full-width" />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption" style="left: 0; bottom: 0;">
                    <p class="retail-caption">Neri's Bakery is first and foremost a family business and we always have an eye on our neighborhood. Our plant is clean and green and our retail store is a local favorite. The Neri family takes pride in being part of our neighbor's lives and celebrations.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does get highlighted, but not everywhere.
I think your problem is because of the captions, there would be many CSS ways to fix this

[image: Take a look at this screenshot showing where we cannot hover]

When we remove your style="left: 0; bottom: 0;" on the captions, the problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you. I set the z index for the previous and it works fine!